# I can't get the file_name of my uploaded file Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my problem, i can't get the uploaded file_name. This is my code :

Controller :

```
$file = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
echo 'value =>'.$file['file_name'];
print_r($file);
```

Result:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: file_name

Filename: controllers/uploading.php

Line Number: 38
value =>Array ( [upload_data] => Array ( [file_name] => Capture9.JPG [file_type] => image/jpeg [file_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/Internship/asset/admin/img/ [full_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/Internship/asset/admin/img/Capture9.JPG [raw_name] => Capture9 [orig_name] => Capture.JPG [client_name] => Capture.JPG [file_ext] => .JPG [file_size] => 30.88 [is_image] => 1 [image_width] => 589 [image_height] => 297 [image_type] => jpeg [image_size_str] => width="589" height="297" ) )
```

Rmk> upload work but i just need to get the filename. Thanks

Comment: Try $file['upload_data']['file_name'];

Answer (score 0):

`file_name` is a property of the array you defined called `$file`. You want to use `$file['upload_data']['file_name']` to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to **multidimensional** array 
 you are trying to access an index in the inner array of `['uploaded_data']` array ! so you have to use `$file['uploaded_data']['file_name']` also it's better to check if `isset` index of that array or not ! :)